# Bootstrap navwalker not display nested subcategories

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wp-nav-walker

I'm using bootstrap navwalker for a wordpress custom theme. I've added two subcategories to a menù element that is nested inside a main nav element, see the screen. I'm noticing that the two nested elements are not displayed, how I can fix this to obtain a 3rd level dropdown?

CODE

```
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-content" id="navbar-shop">
              <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'theme_location' => 'woocommerce-nav',
                    'menu'        => 'Woocommerce Menu',
                    'container'      => false,
                    'depth'          => 2,
                    'menu_class'     => 'navbar-nav mr-auto',
                    'walker'         => new Bootstrap_NavWalker(),
                    'fallback_cb'    => 'Bootstrap_NavWalker::fallback',
                ) );
              ?>
      </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify expected result vs actual result and provide the date from which you generate the manu on the screenshot.

Comment: I think that is clear what I'm expecting, a 3rd level dropdown. The data if you know wordpress are the added menu voice form the dashboard.

Comment: I am also having the same problem. Only 1st and second level menus are listing with sub-menus, third and higher levels are not coming.